# Application.VLookup passes, but doesn't return value

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I've been working with some code for several hours and have hit a wall.  I've got the code to pass through the sub, but it doesn't return the value from the selected range, it always returns `#N/A`.  I have done the vlookup with a formula and get it to return as expected, but I just can't make it work with the VBA application.

I feel certain that this is a formatting error on my part, but I can't figure it out because it looks to me like everything is formatted the same.  If there is an alternate way to execute this, I am open to it.  All objects are declared globally, and I believe the issue is rooted in the `VL_Srch_Rng` range which is in a different workbook, and maybe that is where my mistake is(?).

**Details:** The format of the values that I am looking for is a 3 digit store number a `.` then a 12 digit UPC.  `Source_Bk` and `Dist_Sht` is where the result should land, and the `Mvmt_Bk` and `Mvmt_Sht` `range("H:I")` is where the range being searched is located.  The return value is just a number that reflects units sold.

```
Dim Dist_Sht As Worksheet, Dist_LR As Long, Dist_LC As Long, Source_Bk As Workbook, VL_Rslt As Variant, VL_Find As String, VL_Srch_Rng As Range, Mvmt_LR As Long, Mvmt_LC As Long

Mvmt_Bk.Activate
Mvmt_Sht.Activate
With ActiveSheet
   Range("H:H").Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
   For o = 4 To Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
      Range("H" & o).Value = Range("A" & o) & "." & Range("C" & o).Value
   Next o
   Range("H3").Value = "Lookup Value"
   Range("H4").ColumnWidth = 14
   Range("H:H").NumberFormat = "000.000000000000"
   Range("H:I").Value = Range("H:I").Value

   Mvmt_LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
   Mvmt_LC = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   Set VL_Srch_Rng = Mvmt_Sht.Range(Mvmt_Sht.Cells(8, 3), Mvmt_Sht.Cells(Mvmt_LR, Mvmt_LC))
End With

Source_Bk.Activate
Dist_Sht.Activate
With Dist_Sht
   For u = Dist_LR To 2 Step -1
      If Range("J" & u).Value = "0" Then
         Range("J" & u).EntireRow.Delete
      lse
      For s = 12 To Dist_LC
         If Cells(u, s).Value <> "0" Then
            Cells(u, s).Value = Mid(Cells(1, s), Len(Cells(1, s)) - 7, 3) & "." & Cells(u, 2)
            Cells(u, s).NumberFormat = "000.000000000000"
            Cells(u, s).Value = Cells(u, s).Value
         End If
      Next s
      End If
   Next u
End With
'Run to here for the examples below
   For v = 2 To Dist_LR
      For w = 12 To Dist_LC
         If Cells(v, w) <> 0 Then
            VL_Find = Cells(v, w).Value
            VL_Rslt = Application.VLookup(VL_Find, VL_Srch_Rng, 2, False)
            Dist_Sht.Cells(v, w) = VL_Rslt
            If IsError(VL_Rslt) Then
               Dist_Sht.Cells(v, w).Value = "Not Found"
            End If
         End If
      Next w
   Next v
```

I inserted a column at the far left of the `Dist_Sht` and used the formula `=VLOOKUP(M3,'[Planogram - 52 Weeks Movement by store (2).xlsm]Master'!$H$4:$I$51171,2,FALSE)` and it returns the expected value.

I ran the code up until the comment.  This is the snippet of the search value from `Source_Bk.Dist_Sht`[image]

This is the snippet of the search range (`VL_Srch_Rng`) on `Mvmt_Bk.Mvmt_Sht`.  Obviously these examples don't have matching values, but I assure you there are many in the actual data.
[image]

Comment: @BigBen - Done.  As the code shows, the result should replace the value in the `Dist_Sht` `L` column.

Comment: Your VLOOKUP formula uses column M - `M3` for the lookup value. Is one of your screenshots supposed to include column M?

Comment: The contents of your `With Dist_Sht` block are not qualified. There's a typo in the `lse` condition :) (should be `Else`) that would prevent the code from compiling. Assuming that's a copy/paste error here only and not in your code. If you put a breakpoint on `VL_Rslt = Application.VLookup(VL_Find, VL_Srch_Rng, 2, False)`, and evaluate that statement in the Immediate pane & examine the variables in the Locals pane in the IDE, what do you see?

Comment: @BigBen - I'm an idiot.  `Set VL_Srch_Rng = Mvmt_Sht.Range(Mvmt_Sht.Cells(4, 8), Mvmt_Sht.Cells(Mvmt_LR, 9))` should have been the line.  That said, I am still receiving `#N?A`.

Comment: No that line seems fine. This seems problematic. `VL_Find = Cells(v, w).Value`. You can use column letters within cells, if that helps: `Cells(Mvmt_LR, "H")`. Always help to `Debug.Print` the `Address` of the cell to make sure you've got the right one. `w` starts at 12, which is column `L`?

Comment: @DavidZemens That was a copy/paste error.  The code does say `Else`.

Comment: @BigBen - `VL_Find` shows the expected value when the code is in break mode and you hover over it.  The next line `VL_Rslt = Application.VLookup(VL_Find, VL_Srch_Rng, 2, False)` shows `Error 2042`.  `VL_Rslt` is a `Variant` as you suggested yesterday; should `VL_Find` be something other than a `String`?

Comment: Try `Variant` but it's really hard to debug without your data.

Comment: @BigBen THIS WAS IT!  Thank you so much for all of your help!  Between your help yesterday and today, I'd give you all of the internet points if I could!

Comment: Happy to help out, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Shout out to @BigBen The main issue was that `VL_Find` needed to be a `variant`, other issues included a typo that resulted in setting the `Mvmt_srch_Rng` across the wrong array.
    Dim VL_Find as Variant

```
Mvmt_Bk.Activate
Mvmt_Sht.Activate
With ActiveSheet
   Range("H:H").Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
   For o = 4 To Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
      Range("H" & o).Value = Range("A" & o) & "." & Range("C" & o).Value
   Next o
   Range("H3").Value = "Lookup Value"
   Range("H4").ColumnWidth = 14
   Range("H:H").NumberFormat = "000.000000000000"
   Range("H:I").Value = Range("H:I").Value

   Mvmt_LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
   Mvmt_LC = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   Set VL_Srch_Rng = Mvmt_Sht.Range(Mvmt_Sht.Cells(4, "H"), Mvmt_Sht.Cells(Mvmt_LR, "I"))
End With
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized

Source_Bk.Activate
Dist_Sht.Activate
With ActiveSheet
   For u = Dist_LR To 2 Step -1
      If Range("J" & u).Value = "0" Then
         Range("J" & u).EntireRow.Delete
      Else
      For s = 12 To Dist_LC
         If Cells(u, s).Value <> "0" Then
            Cells(u, s).Value = Mid(Cells(1, s), Len(Cells(1, s)) - 7, 3) & "." & Cells(u, 2)
            Cells(u, s).NumberFormat = "000.000000000000"
            Cells(u, s).Value = Cells(u, s).Value
         End If
      Next s
      End If
   Next u

   For v = 2 To Dist_LR
      For w = 12 To Dist_LC
         If Cells(v, w) <> 0 Then
            VL_Find = Cells(v, w).Value
            VL_Rslt = Application.VLookup(VL_Find, VL_Srch_Rng, 2, False)
            Dist_Sht.Cells(v, w) = VL_Rslt
            Dist_Sht.Cells(v, w).NumberFormat = 0
            If IsError(VL_Rslt) Then
               Dist_Sht.Cells(v, w).Value = "Not Found"
            End If
         End If
      Next w
   Next v
```

Comment: You might still be able to get this to work with a stricter type than `Variant`, perhaps `Double` (assuming all of the values are numeric in nature). It looks like you've got numeric values. But Excel is sometimes finicky about strings that look like numbers (e.g., numbers that are stored as strings).